# Importing different files with python

Tags: python

How can I import different .py files in python based on user-input?

```
def main():
    FileName = input(">")
    file = FileName.replace(".py", "")
    import file
    print(test) #from the file imported

main()
```

Something like this, so I can import a certain file created with the name of the user input, and that file imported contains a string or a list and so I could print that string or list within the main python file.

Comment: Be aware that this could well count as a security vulnerability if you don't take steps to limit which files on the filesystem can be imported. Importing a python program runs it, so importing a malicious file could be dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) from `importlib`

```
from importlib import import_module

file = import_module(FileName.replace(".py", ""))
print(file.test)
```